# Matlab parallel pool starts 4 cores but only 1 worker

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I have an i7 6700k. If I instruct parpool to start a parallel pool with 4 workers, it starts 4 processors (as I can see in my task manager) but still says "connected to 1 workers". When I execute a job in a parfor-loop, only one core is running the job.

I have sepcified NumWorkers to 4 in my local cluster profile. My computer runs Windows 10.

What is the error and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What's your MATLAB and PCT version?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I am running Matlab 2016a, and the paralell computing toolbox that was release together with Matlab 2016a.

Comment: This sounds like an installation problem. Contact MathWorks technical support to help resolve it.